# How to write a ruby script to handle http messages (server side)

Tags: android, ruby

I used HttpUrlConnection & AsyncTask classes in Android to perform an HTTP GET and POST request in order to upload and download an image to/from a server correspondingly. I must write a Ruby script on server side to handle these requests. I managed to authenticate the user but i don't know how to store and send the image on/from the server to the Android application and also how to create a folder containing all the user data (images) on server side. Could anyone please help me with that part? I have attached the code in Ruby that i managed to write:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

use Rack::Auth::Basic, "Restricted Area" do |username,password|
  username=='user' and password=='user1'
end

get '/' do 

end

post '/' do
end
```

Answer (score 1):

for build script on ruby send file you need two libs `net/http`, `uri`

some simple example

```
require "net/http"
require "uri"

#Simple requiest
uri = URI.parse("http://search.com/")
response = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)

#Example with auth
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
request.basic_auth("username", "password")

# Use nokogiri to parse response.body.
# Sent file
TOKEN = "SOMEWORD"
file = "/path/to/your/file"
post_body = []
post_body << "--#{TOKEN}rn"
post_body << `Content-Disposition:form-data;name="datafile";filename="#{File.basename(file)}"rn`
post_body << "Content-Type: you_file_type"
post_body << "rn"
post_body << File.read(file)
post_body << "rn--#{TOKEN}--rn"

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
request.body = post_body.join
request["Content-Type"] = "multipart/form-data, boundary=#{TOKEN}"
http.request(request)
.....
and more
```

Read this [HTTP](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/index.html)

Comment: First of all thanks a lot for the response!!!!! but my issue is to handle the HTTP request on the server side not to perform one. I send an HTTP POST request from the android application in order to upload an image an i want from the server side (ie ruby script) to store this image on a folder.Correspondingly i want to send an HTTP GET request from the android application in order to fetch the image from the server.